# How can I Fetch data after selecting from dropdown list with php ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, dropdown

This is my select code here I have made a table of `teacher_subject` where the `class_id` and `section_id` is stored for a teacher who will make the result.

**For ex:** a teacher of class 2 section B subject maths. A database table of teacher subject just constitutes the id of class, section & subject.

Now I have made three different tables as such for class, section & subject.

So what my code is doing is from teacher_subject table is fetching the data of a particular `teacher(t_id)` and the class id is in $class and the class name is in echo $rows_clse['t_class'];(like class 1,2,....)

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm mr-2" name="class" id="class" onChange="getsection(this.value);">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <?php  
    $sql_cls="select * from $tb_teacher_subject where school_id='$school_id' and t_id='$sessid' and status='active'";
    $res_cls = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_cls);
    if($res_cls){
        if($nums_cls=mysqli_num_rows($res_cls) > 0){
            while($rows_cls = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_cls)){ 
                $class = $rows_cls['t_class_id'];

    ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $rows_cls['t_class_id']; ?>,<?php echo $rows_cls['id']; ?>">
                <?php
                $sql_clse = "select * from $tb_class where school_id='$school_id' and id='$class'";
                $res_clse = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_clse);
                if($res_clse){
                    while($rows_clse = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_clse)){
                        echo $rows_clse['t_class'];
                    }
                }  
                ?>
                </option>
    <?php 

            }
        }
    }


    ?>
    </select>
    <select name="section" id="section-list" class="form-control form-control-sm mr-2">
        <option value="">Select</option>
```

**my script code is:**

```
function getsection(val){
    var str = val;
    var ddata = str.split(",");
    var class_id = ddata[0];
    var id = ddata[1];
    $.ajax({
        //the url to send the data to
        url: "model/results/result_edit.php?getsection",
        //the data to send to
        // data: 'class_id='+val,
        data: {class_id : class_id, id: id},

        //type. for eg: GET, POST
        type: "POST",
        //on success
        success: function(data){
            console.log("***********success***************");
            console.log(data);
            $("#section-list").html(data);

        },
        //on error
        error: function(){
             console.log("***********Error***************"); //You can remove here
             console.log(data); //You can remove here
        }
    });
    //console.log($id);
}
```

**and the php code is:**

```
<?php 
    // Select all Data **********************/
    if(isset($_GET['getsection'])){
        $cls = $_POST['class_id'];
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $sql_section = "select * from $tb_teacher_subject where t_class='$cls' and id='$id'";
        $res_section = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_section);
        if($res_section){
            while($row_sec = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_section)){ 
                $sec = $row_sec['t_section'];
?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row_sec['t_section'] ?>"> 
                <?php
                $sql_clse = "select * from $tb_section where school_id='$school_id' and id='$sec'";
                $res_clse = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_clse);
                if($res_clse){
                    while($rows_clse = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_clse)){
                        echo $rows_clse['t_section'];
                    }

                }  ?>
                </option>                
<?php
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Now what do i want is if clicked on class 1 it will show section A and B as teacher of class 1 teaches in two sections A & B but what my problem is when clicked on 'select' option of class it shows 1, 2, 1 means it shows class 1, class 2, class 1 and when I click on the first class(class1) then it shows A and when I click on the third one it shows B. So is there anyone can help me with my codes.

It would be a great help if you help me if my words are confusing then you can check my database table I am pasting a pic of it. [class table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96emN.jpg), [section table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mN03.jpg), [teacher_subject table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVaTh.jpg). Please help me with showing codes